# cmake FetchContent_Declare: Is there a way to have FetchContent not bring in the git repo submodules?

Tags: git, cmake, git-submodules

I use `FetchContent` in my `CMakeLists.txt` to bring in a git repo I need for my build. Everything works fine. However, it also brings in a (large) submodule I don't need for the build. It seems that content fetching will update the submodules even if `GIT_SUBMODULES ""` argument is not present under `FetchContent_Declare`.
So, how do I achieve that? cmake's documentation isn't very clear for this use case.

Comment: Just to add - I found a hack to work around this problem: I set `GIT_SUBMODULES` to a directory that holds no submodule. This works, but it is quite ugly.

Comment: Did you mean to say "_will update the submodules even if GIT_SUBMODULES "" argument **is** present under FetchContent_Declare_"? See [the docs for `ExternalProject_Add`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_add) and what they say about `GIT_SUBMODULES`.